# Istio-Service to service communication is not happening as expected

Tags: istio

i have one service which has sidecar and one service without sidecar.
I am making a request(POST) from the service with sidecar to the service without a sidecar which also runs on HTTPS.

I am getting below error in the logs.
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for “”: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Am I missing something here due to which i am seeing this error?

Comment: how do you route traffic outside of the mesh(to service B without sidecar)? At least you need a service entry?  do you have any ?

Comment: @chilu Have you been managed to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to disable mTLS for the service without a sidecar by a DestinationRule, something like:

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3"
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: default
  namespace: foo
spec:
  host: bar.foo.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: DISABLE
EOF
```

Comment: I have added the destination rule but still the communication from service with sidecar in istio is not happening to service without sidecar in the mesh.